# I need help figuring out this formula or need a suggestion on coming up with a better formula on ACCESS

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, switch-statement, iif

I need help with these formulas, i tried using this one but it told me it was to long

=IIf([Combo5]=“Building Service Engineer”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text787],IIf([Combo5]=“Carpenter”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text788],IIf([Combo5]=“Custodian”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text789],IIf([Combo5]=“Custodian - Shift Pay (5am - 6am)”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text790],IIf([Combo5]=“Electrician”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text791],IIf([Combo5]=“Facilities Project Supervisor”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text792],IIf([Combo5]=“Fire Marshal”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text793],IIf([Combo5]=“Gardening Specialist”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text794],IIf([Combo5]=“Grounds Worker”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text795],IIf([Combo5]=“Interior Design”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text796],IIf([Combo5]=“Irrigation Specialist”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text797],IIf([Combo5]=“Laborer”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text798],IIf([Combo5]=“Lead Auto/Equip Mechanic”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text799],IIf([Combo5]=“Lead Custodian”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text800],IIf([Combo5]=“Lead Grounds Worker”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text801],IIf([Combo5]=“Light Auto/Equip Operator”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text802],IIf([Combo5]=“Locksmith”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text803],IIf([Combo5]=“Maintenance Mechanic”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text804],IIf([Combo5]=“Painter”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text805],IIf([Combo5]=“Pest Control Specialist”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text806],IIf([Combo5]=“Plumber”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text807],IIf([Combo5]=“Recycler (Laborer)”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text808],IIf([Combo5]=“Refrigeration Mechanic”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text809],IIf([Combo5]=“Supervising Building Service Engineer”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text810],0)))))))))))))))))))))))))

So I approced it as a SWITCH functnion

=Switch([Combo5]=“Building Service Engineer”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text787],[Combo5]=“Carpenter”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text788],[Combo5]=“Custodian”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text789],[Combo5]=“Custodian - Shift Pay (5am - 6am)”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text790],[Combo5]=“Electrician”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text791],[Combo5]=“Facilities Project Supervisor”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text792],[Combo5]=“Fire Marshal”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text793],[Combo5]=“Gardening Specialist”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text794],[Combo5]=“Grounds Worker”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text795],[Combo5]=“Interior Design”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text796],[Combo5]=“Irrigation Specialist”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text797],[Combo5]=“Laborer”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text798],[Combo5]=“Lead Auto/Equip Mechanic”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text799],[Combo5]=“Lead Custodian”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text800],[Combo5]=“Lead Grounds Worker”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text801],[Combo5]=“Light Auto/Equip Operator”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text802],[Combo5]=“Locksmith”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text803],[Combo5]=“Maintenance Mechanic”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text804],[Combo5]=“Painter”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text805],[Combo5]=“Pest Control Specialist”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text806],[Combo5]=“Plumber”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text807],[Combo5]=“Recycler (Laborer)”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text808],[Combo5]=“Refrigeration Mechanic”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text809],[Combo5]=“Supervising Building Service Engineer”,[Forms]![Estimate]![Text810])

That didnt work so I used it as a module

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function fncRetValBasedOnCmb4() As String
Select Case Forms!ReportFinished!Combo4
    Case "Building Service Engineer"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text787
    Case "Carpenter"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text788
    Case "Custodian"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text789
    Case "Custodian - Shift Pay (5am - 6am)"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text790
    Case "Electrician"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text791
    Case "Facilities Project Supervisor"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text792
    Case "Fire Marshal"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text793
    Case "Gardening Specialist"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text794
    Case "Grounds Worker"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text795
    Case "Interior Design"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text796
    Case "Irrigation Specialist"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text797
    Case "Laborer"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text798
    Case "Lead Auto/Equip Mechanic"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text799
    Case "Lead Custodian"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text800
    Case "Lead Grounds Worker"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text801
    Case "Light Auto/Equip Operator"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text802
    Case "Locksmith"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text803
    Case "Maintenance Mechanic"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text804
    Case "Painter"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text805
    Case "Pest Control Specialist"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text806
    Case "Plumber"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text807
    Case "Recycler (Laborer)"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text808
    Case "Refrigeration Mechanic"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text809
    Case "Supervising Building Service Engineer"
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = Forms!Estimate!Text810
    Case Else
        fncRetValBasedOnCmb4 = 0
End Select
```

End Function

The thing is i do not know how to trigger this

---

I have a form where the data is entered
and im trying to create a new form with a few combo boxes that once selected it will show the amount associated in an unbound text box (calculated field from the first form)

Answer (score 0):

How about placing the formula:

```
=fncRetValBasedOnCmb4()
```

in the Control Source of your unbound text box?